# "Проголошувати незалежність" чи "оголошувати незалежність"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, вибір-слова

Читала статтю в інтернеті і стикнулася з таким варіантом, як "оголошувати незалежність". То як правильно, "оголошувати" чи "проголошувати"?

Answer (score 3):

[Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/vugoloshuvatu,-ogoloshuvatu,-progoloshuvatu)

[image]

[Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53394/30285.html)

> ***Оголошувати, оголосити, -ошу, -осиш***. Публічно заявляти про щось, робити відомим; офіційно заявляти про початок чогось тощо.
>   Вж. зі сл.: вирок, наказ, присуд, подяку, порядок денний, рішення,
>   війну, тривогу, похід.
>
> ***Проголошувати, проголосити***. **1.** Декларувати, обнародувати. Вж. зі сл.: братерство, єдність, закон, незалежність,
>   рівність, свободу совісті. **2.** Те саме, що виголошувати. Вж. зі сл.:
>   промову, монолог, тост, свої думки.

***Правильно "проголошувати незалежність"***

Comment: Але про незалежність можна теж *публічно заявити*, чи не так? В чому ж відмінність якщо так.

Comment: @Yola на мою думку, оголошувати (першочергова дія "Оголошення незалежності може супроводжуватися прийняттям декларації про незалежність.") проголошувати (остаточний факт тощо, що це відбулося "шлях, що пройшов український народ від Декларації про Державний суверенітет (16 липня) до проголошення незалежності держави"). Проте я можу помилятися.

Comment: Почитав іще [тут](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) і [тут](http://sum.in.ua/s/deklaruvaty) - тепер повна плутанина.

Comment: @Yola і мене заплутали))

Answer (score 1):

Гадаю, що правильним варіантом буде "проголошувати незалежність".

Перш за все, маємо "[Акт **проголошення** незалежності України](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8)".

Також, [Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53394/30285.html) (інформація взята із Літературного слововживання) пише, що потрібно казати "проголошувати незалежність" (однак врахуйте, що саме дієслово "проголошувати" також може й вживатися у тому ж значенні, що й "виголошувати").

На іншій сторінці [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53394/26339.html) (інформація із Уроків державної мови (з газети «Хрещатик») ) також пише, що потрібно казати "проголошувати незалежність". Синоніми - декларувати, обнародувати.

В Інтернеті також зустрічаємо вислів "проголошення незалежності", а не "оголошення" чи "виголошення".